# Why does principal returns as type Object in spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, logout

I have added blocking user functionality on the site.

I add `isBlocked` to my `UserModel`. When I user try to login - this fields checks.

Problem retains for already logged user. I want to force log out it when admin block user.

I have read following topic:

[How do you log out all logged in users in spring-security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751964/how-do-you-log-out-all-logged-in-users-in-spring-security)

But I have not ideas how to check that principal(`java.lang.Object` actually) related with user.

Comment: Just debug it and you'll see what concrete object you will get as principal. Take a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html#getPrincipal() , in simplest case it will be a username.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235997/how-to-access-http-sessions-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principal is the object that you have to use in order to identify a user. Once identified you can expired the session of that user. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5025140/1283348) you will find a nice explanation on what a Principal is in Spring.

You can cast the principal to the appropriate Class, but you have to know it before. The Class of the principal could be `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` or whatever, it depends on how you are using SpringSecurity.

A quick way to know what is the correct Class is debugging the solution commented in the link you provided.

Comment: ok it works for me without classCastException but it strange for me using explicit class cast